# Как определить пользовательские и библиотечные функции?

Tags: c++, c, строки, функции

Я получил эту задачу, проблема в том, что я даже не понимаю, как должен работать код, я не знаю, как идентифицировать пользовательскую функцию или отличить библиотечную функцию от моего кода, написав задачу, пожалуйста, если вы можете объяснить реализацию, я буду очень рад
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, надо проверить, есть ли определение данной функции в программе - тогда она пользовательская, нет - библиотечная (если, конечно, вызывается). Если такая *функция* вообще не упоминается - то no function...

Comment: Ну если хотите «круто» решить, то стройте дерево AST, по нему очень легко будет ответить на вопрос. Думаю, какая-то часть Clang может в этом помочь.

Comment: Поскольку вам задан очень упрощённый синтаксис, можно попробовать описать грамматику и разбирать с помощью bison+flex https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=yTXCPGAD3SQ

Comment: Ну и вот гуглится миллион готовых решений, типа https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html